# Issue in moving an object across the screen

Tags: java

can someone enlighten me.

I am doing a game were a ball needs to automatically be created and move across the screen from one corner to the other.

I was able to create balls and move them from the bottom right corner to the top left and vice versa, but I can't figure out how to do it from the bottom left corner to the top right.

Attached is some of the code and a graph of my logic.[Logic of how the balls will move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO8dZ.jpg)

```
case 1: // From one side to the other, in two axes

        switch (subScenario) {
        case 0: // Bottom right corner to top left corner.
            posX = panelWidth;
            posY = panelHeight;
            directionX = (rnd.nextInt(2) + 1)*-1;
            directionY = directionX;
        case 1: // Top left corner to bottom right
            posX = 0;
            posY = 0;
            directionX = (rnd.nextInt(2) + 1)*1;
            directionY = directionX;
        case 2: // Bottom left corner to top right corner
            posX = 0;
            posY = panelHeight;
            directionX = directionY;
            directionY = (rnd.nextInt(2) + 1)*-1;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: So where is the error?

Comment: Try switching directionX and directionY lines in case 2

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, didn't think for a second there. Set `directionX=(rnd.nextInt(2) + 1)*1` and leave `directionY` as is

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard to achieve. Just make the y-direction negative and add an offset (i.e. instead of y=f(x) it would be y=offset-f(x)). The offset would be `panelHeight` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move left to right, as in `case 2`, `directionX` must be positive. Therefore:

```
directionX = (rnd.nextInt(2) + 1)*1;
```

`directionY` should be negative, so:

```
directionY = directionX*-1;
```

Also, remember to put `break` after each `case` so that they all don't activate.